# Building an fftw2 application with fftw3 libraries

Tags: fftw

I'm trying to build an old application that depends on `fftw`. It was written against fftw2 and I am currently on fftw3 (specifically 3.3.8). It fails to link because of undefined reference to `fftw_create_plan` and `fftw_one`. Indeed, my libfftw does not have those functions anymore; the following returns nothing:

```
readelf -s /usr/lib/libfftw3.so | grep 'fftw_create_plan\|fftw_one'
```

It looks like the api has changed significantly since the code was written. Is there a compatibility layer I can use or should I just go learn fftw3's new interface?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot link an FFTW2 code against FFTW3 libraries, as you are coming to realize yourself. There is also no complete interface between the two, cause the apis are really not compatible.

Having said that, you may of course link your code against FFTW2 libraries. You still can obtain them. Why is that not an option?

Comment: fftw2 is no longer packaged in arch, and I assume others will eventually follow -- I want to keep the program current. Just wasn't expecting to have to rewrite significant parts of it! But to be honest so far I prefer fftw3's interface, so it's not a loss.

Comment: Sure. I wasn't aware that you were willing to do the porting. Fftw2 is built and installed quickly though. I'd do it at least to be able to test the new version.